# VBAで、True + 1　が　0　と計算されるのはなぜ？

Tags: vba

ExcelのVBAで以下のコードを実行すると0と表示されます。
Trueが1に変換され、2と表示されることを想定していました。
なぜこのようなことが起きるのでしょうか。

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox (True + 1)  
End Sub
```

Comment: 関連した内容を扱っている投稿です: ["Casting a boolean to an integer returns -1 for true?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3621037/5989200) -- 本家 Stack Overflow

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VBAにおける`True`は数値に変換すると`1`ではなく`-1`となります。そのため`True + 1`は`0`になります。
なお、`False`は`0`です。

Answer (score 0):

MsgBox (3 And 5) ← 1
  0000000000000011 ← 3
  And
  0000000000000101 ← 5
   ↓
  0000000000000001 ← 1
MsgBox (3 Or 5) ← 7
  0000000000000011 ← 3
  Or
  0000000000000101 ← 5
   ↓
  0000000000000111 ← 7
(Visual)Basic では、２進数の各ビット毎に論理演算を行います。
すべてのビットがTrue つまり 1111111111111111 は -1 になります。